# Magento homepage appears and not the intended website

Tags: magento, vps

I have restored magento website from a backup. I have restored files and database without any issues. Also, I did configuration in local.xml file with the DB credentials.I am getting Magento home page now.

But I restored my custom website, so my home page should be that instead of a magento home page. Can someone please help me where I would be going wrong. Any ideas or thoughts would be really appreciated.

FYI, this is hosted in GoDaddy VPS with cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

check in admin CMS-> pages home page is active and its configuration/design is correct in cms